# optimizing function manipulating string (heap memory allocation)

Tags: rust, memory

I have am doing an exercise, I should only use standard package.
the point is to take all words of a vector of strings and output only the initials.
["One Two","Three"] -> ["O. T.","T."]
I got it working with a "naive explicit" code :

```
pub fn initials_explicit_heavy(texts: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut texts_initials: Vec<String> = vec![];
    for one_text in texts {
        let mut one_text_initials: String = "".to_string();
        for word in one_text.split_whitespace() {
            let first: char = word.chars().next().unwrap();
            let first_and_dot: String = first.to_string() + ". ";
            one_text_initials += &first_and_dot;
        }
        texts_initials.push(one_text_initials.trim_end().to_string());
        // texts_initials.push(one_text_initials);
    }
    texts_initials
}
```

But then the function allocate too much heap memory, indeed.
51 instead of 38 times.
I am unsure where is the issue.
Should I use iterators instead of for loop ?
Avoid all those to_string() conversions ?
or use some magic method I overlooked ?
Any hint is really welcome.

------ edit -----
my apologizes, I forgot to mention that function type sugnature is frozen.

```
(texts: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<String>
```

Comment: The minimum number of allocations you need for this is one for the result vector plus one for each string in the result vector, excluding potentially empty strings or vectors. Your surplus allocations result from iteratively building the strings, which can result in multiple allocations for each string. An easy improvement is using string formatting when building `first_and_dot`. You can also first add up the number of bytes needed for each initial, allocate a string of the right size and then build the string in a second pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily that you need to use iterators. In fact it's quite inconvenient to use iterators for your task. The reason why you have so many allocations, is because you do them often, basically every time you try to cast something to string (e.g. for each text you do `"".to_string()` and `one_text_initials.trim_end().to_string()`, and also for each word you do `first.to_string()` and `one_text_initials += &first_and_dot;`, which most likely will need reallocation to accomodate more data.

Here's a possible modification, that does a few allocations preemtively and then only one allocation per text (on the line `texts_initials.push(one_text_initials.iter().collect())`):

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ee552b4a1d5092978fdf141538b558d)

```rust
pub fn initials_explicit_lighter(texts: Vec<&str>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut texts_initials: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut one_text_initials: Vec<char> = vec![]; 
    for one_text in texts {
        one_text_initials.clear();
        let mut words = one_text.split_whitespace();
        
        // handle first word without space
        if let Some(word) = words.next() {
            let first: char = word.chars().next().unwrap();
            one_text_initials.push(first);
            one_text_initials.push('.');
        }
        
        // the rest of the words with space
        for word in words {
            let first: char = word.chars().next().unwrap();
            one_text_initials.push(' ');
            one_text_initials.push(first);
            one_text_initials.push('.');
        }
        texts_initials.push(one_text_initials.iter().collect());
    }
    
    texts_initials
}
```

Notice that `one_text_initials` also grows for every word, but since `one_text_initials` is preallocated outside the loop, every time I use `one_text_initials.clear()` only the  size of the vector is reset to 0, while the allocated memory is not freed, thus for the next words it's less likely to reallocate memory

Comment: `"".to_string()` doesn't allocate, there is a [check in `RawVec` for `capacity == 0`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#168-172) which is where the allocation would happen.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexey your code pass the instruction's "heaps allocation threshold" and is very understandable.
Sven 's one sounds to be more performant but at a cost of being less "noob-friendly".

Comment: You can use `String` instead of `Vec<char>`, which avoids the temporary buffer. It is also more compact.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an improved version of your code that tries to stay as close to your version as possible:

```
pub fn initials_explicit_heavy(texts: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut texts_initials: Vec<String> = vec![];
    for one_text in texts {
        let mut one_text_initials: String = "".to_string();
        for word in one_text.split_whitespace() {
            let first: char = word.chars().next().unwrap();
            write!(one_text_initials, "{}. ", first).ok();
        }
        one_text_initials.pop();
        texts_initials.push(one_text_initials);
    }
    texts_initials
}
```

Improvements:

1. Accept a slice as parameter. No need to consume a vector.
2. Use the `write!()` macro to write to the allocated string. This saves all the intermediate allocations for `first.to_string()`.
3. Simply pop off the last character to deal with the trailing space. This will do nothing if the string is empty, and saves the allocation otherwise required for `one_text_initials.trim_end().to_string()`

You can further improve the number of reallocations by precalculating the number of bytes you need for `one_text_initials` and allocating the result vector with the correct size immediately:

```
pub fn initials_explicit_heavy(texts: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut texts_initials: Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(texts.len());
    for one_text in texts {
        let initials_len = one_text
            .split_whitespace()
            .map(|word| word.chars().next().unwrap().len_utf8() + 2)
            .sum::<usize>();
        let mut one_text_initials = String::with_capacity(initials_len);
        for word in one_text.split_whitespace() {
            let first: char = word.chars().next().unwrap();
            write!(one_text_initials, "{}. ", first).ok();
        }
        one_text_initials.pop();
        texts_initials.push(one_text_initials);
    }
    texts_initials
}
```

This code uses the minimal number of allocations that's required to build the return value, so that aspect can't be improved any further. You could still reduce the code duplication by defining an iterator that returns the initials.

And finally, here's a version of the function implemented in my personal style, with input from the comments (rather than trying to stay close to your code):

```
pub fn initials_string_vec(strings: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    strings.iter().copied().map(initials_string).collect()
}

pub fn initials_string(s: &str) -> String {
    let len = initials(s).map(|c| c.len_utf8() + 2).sum::<usize>();
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(len);
    result.extend(initials(s).flat_map(|c| [c, '.', ' ']));
    result.pop();
    result
}

pub fn initials(s: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + '_ {
    s.split_whitespace().filter_map(|word| word.chars().next())
}
```

(I'd usually not bother implementing `initials_string_vec()` at all, since all it does is mapping an existing function over a slice.)

Comment: Although it seems unlikely that it's a major cost compared to the allocations, it might also be more efficient to [`String::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push) the letter, period, and space (possibly `extend` from a slice?) than to invoke the formatting machinery.

Comment: From the first sentence I would also think it likely that the input is ascii-only, which could lead to a few optimisations (e.g. no need to precisely compute the UTF length of every first character).

Comment: Also doubt it leads to better machine code, but `word.chars().next()` could be a `filter_map` tacked onto the `split_whitespace`, to avoid unwrapping.

Comment: @Masklinn I only focused on the allocation count here, because I think that's what the question was mainly about. I intentionally only changed what was required to reduce the allocation count.

Comment: there is no precision about the range of character the code should be working with. But the tested inputs are only basic utf8 strings.

Comment: @Masklinn I added another version taking into account your comments.

Comment: Thanks Sven, your solution seems more performant , and there is more learning in it for me.
I may just pick Alexey answer since it will probably be more directly helpfull to a someone in the same situation as me.